# About a special way to find the average waiting time to get a sequence

Tags: probability, average

A friend of mine taught me the following question:

You have a coin. When you toss it up, heads you note $1$, tails you note $0$. Then, tossing it up repeatedly, let's find the average waiting time to get each $111, 011, 101101$.

Let $E(L)$ be the average waiting time to get a sequence $L$.

This question can be solved by drawing tree diagram. For example, you get
$$x=\frac12(1+x)+\frac14(2+x)+\frac18(3+x)+\frac18\times3$$ where $E(111)=x$. Then, you get $E(111)=x=14$.

By the same way as above, you get $E(011)=8, E(101101)=74$.

However, this way is not so good for larger sequences. My friend taught me a great way to solve this without any proof.

Suppose that a pattern $L$ has $k$ numbers. Let us say there exists 'a length-$r$-overlap' if the last $r$ numbers of $L$ is equal to the first $r$ numbers of $L$. Then, for $r=1,2,\cdots,k$, a leading number is defined as the following:

$\epsilon_r=1$ if there exists a length-$r$-overlap.

$\epsilon_r=0$ if there doesnt't exist a length-$r$-overlap.

Note that $\epsilon_k=1, E(L)=\sum_{r=1}^k\epsilon_r2^r.$

By using this way, we can get $E(111), E(011), E(101101)$ very easily.

*1.* Noting $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2=\epsilon_3=1$, $E(111)=2^1+2^2+2^3=14.$

*2.* Noting $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2=0, \epsilon_3=1$, $E(011)=2^3=8.$

*3.* Noting $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_3=\epsilon_6=1, \epsilon_2=\epsilon_4=\epsilon_5=0$, $E(101101)=2^1+2^3+2^6=74.$

Then, here are my questions.

**Question 1** : What is the name of this way? (Is this way famous?)

**Question 2** : Could you show me how to prove that the average waiting time can be found by this way?

Comment: I call it Conway's algorithm

Comment: as in http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12174/time-taken-to-hit-a-pattern-of-heads-and-tails-in-a-series-of-coin-tosses/12178#12178 apparently first described by Martin Gardner in 1974 in "On the paradoxical situations that arise from nontransitive relations". Scientific American 231 (4): 120–125.

Comment: @Henry: Thank you for nice information!